# Search Bar And Search Bar Controller in Nested View (iOS)

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a search controller to a table view header and can't figure out how to do it with a nested view. I'm using a nested view because I want to have a segment control in the header as well under the search box:

[image: Layout]

[image: Storyboard]

It seems like the search bar controller wants to be a direct child of the table header and it breaks whenever you click into the search box:

Clicking into the search box makes the box slide all the way to the left off the screen:
[image: clicking into search]

And after clicking done the search box is gone:
[image: after search]

I've created an example [project on github](https://github.com/jamescharlesworth/SearchSubView) where you can see exactly what I'm describing. I saw some similar answers but they were dealing with UISearchBar and not embedding the SearchBar and Controller

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution using the new UISearchView class thanks to this [blog post](http://tsuharesu.com/ios8-searchcontroller-without-searchbar/). I've created a [branch](https://github.com/jamescharlesworth/SearchSubView/tree/UISearchView) in my example github repo with the solution. Basically you don't create the searchbar in the Storyboard, you add it to the view in the classes init method.